# how to pause R and resume it later?

Tags: r

I have  a very big dataset with more than 100 millions of rows. I am running a loop on that dataset. The code has been running since two days ago and I forgot to add a counter to see how much time is left. I am working at a place that the desks are first come first serve so you cannot have a specific desk and at the end of each day, you have to logout the system. 
My problem is if I logout the system, I will loose the two days of work. Is there any way that I can pause R, logout my system, come back tomorrow morning and resume my work? I am working with UNIX. I appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Regards,
Mahsa

Comment: I've never heard of a way to do this, unfortunately...

Comment: You're using UNIX. Are you logging into a cluster, or an individual workstation?

Comment: Regardless, it is not recommended running loops in R on 100 MM data set. You could potentially post a new question on how to vectorize your code. It may well be that with some improvement your code could run in a matter of minutes or hour or two

Comment: @DavidArenburg - Kudos. This is the best approach.

Comment: And if your code can't finish in an hour or two after optimization in R, it is time to convert to Python/Julia or even something even lower level.

Answer (score 9):

If you're on a unix system, you'll most likely have access to a program called "screen".

If it's available, you can open up a terminal, start screen, start R, then close the terminal while R is still running in the background.

Then at a later time, or the next day, you simply open up another terminal, and use screen to connect back into the previously created session.

the steps:

1. in your terminal, start screen

   ```
   screen
   ```
2. start R, and run your program
3. Close your terminal, just click the x, don't ctrl-d.

...hours later

4. open a new terminal, type

   ```
   screen -ls
   ```

   to get a list of currently running screen sessions
5. reconnect to the session of your choosing

   ```
   screen -r 34234
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you can send the process to run in the background by following the below procedure:

1. For illustration i have created a file with sleep command with sleep time of 500 seconds

   `[prompt ~]$ cat test.sh`

   `sleep 500`
2. Once the test script is in execution mode, please <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to send the process to background. and then enter `bg 1`, so that the process runs in the background.

-

```
[prompt ~]$ sh test.sh 

[1]+  Stopped                 sh test.sh

[prompt ~]$ 

[prompt ~]$ bg 1

[1]+ sh test.sh &

[prompt ~]$ 

[prompt ~]$ ps -ef | grep -i test.sh

user1 20683 17618  0 16:08 pts/17   00:00:00 sh test.sh

user1 20925 17618  0 16:08 pts/17   00:00:00 grep -i test.sh
```