# R: Resuming work after mac sleeping

Tags: r, macos

I know in Matlab if I put the lid down and mac sleeps, it can resume the work if there were some computations running. But is it possible in R as well? I'm afraid to close the lid down so that I don't waste the time spent.

I know I can `caffeinate` it, but I dont want it to overheat while transporting home. I read it is possible to [resume the session on UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848975/how-to-pause-r-and-resume-it-later), but does it work on **OSX as well?**

If the `screen` options worked on OSX, I guess if I didnt do the first step before starting the computation now is too late right?

Comment: It should work fine, works on my windows 7 and linux

Comment: Ok the battery is running low anyway, so lets hope for the best :D

Comment: Try this, save all your work and just have a file with pseudo code. Put the machine to sleep and resume

Comment: What do you mean by a file with pseudo code?

Comment: just something, like df <- data.frame(col1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5), col2 <- (6,7,8,9,10)). Once the data frame is in the data put it to sleep and when you resume you will know if the code and the data still persist

Comment: @Dinesh.hmn: I think for  the question posed one would need a test like:  `j = numeric(1e7);  for (i in 1:1e7){ j=log(1+1)}`